# Controlling the width of the vertical scroll bar

Tags: init-file

I am using emacs 24.5 under Linux Gentoo, and I would like to adjust the vertical scroll bar width, as I notice it became much larger than it was in a recent revision.

How to do this in my ".emacs" file ?
I tried to manually set variable scroll-bar-width, but emacs reports it does not know this variable (although I came across it while reading the documentation).

Alternatively, I could live without the scroll bar after all (more text space is always fine with me).

Comment: I just downloaded the stable public release for 24.5.1, and typed `M-x describe-variable RET scroll-bar-width RET` and this is the result:  "*`scroll-bar-width` is a variable defined in 'C source code'.  Its value is `nil`.  Automatically becomes buffer-local when set.  Documentation:
Width of this buffer's scroll bars in pixels.  A value of `nil` means to use the scroll bar width from the window's frame.*"  You might try something like this in your `.emacs` file:  `(setq-default scroll-bar-width 15)` and restart Emacs.  See also the *function* `set-window-scroll-bars`.

Comment: To eliminate the scroll bar entirely, you could use:  `(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(vertical-scroll-bars . nil))`

Answer (score 4):

Probably depends on your Emacs (e.g. toolkit or not).

On MS Windows, I control it using frame parameter `scroll-bar-width` (see also `scroll-bar-height`).

See the Elisp manual, node [Layout Parameters](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Layout-Parameters.html).